cvxpy Python MPC controller - update reference variable xref based on manipulated variable u at each predictive time step
for t in range(horizon_length):

    # Here, xref[:, t] needs to be calculated from u[:, t].value
    cost += cvxpy.quad_form(x[:, t] - xref[:, t], Q)  
    cost += cvxpy.quad_form(u[:, t], R)  
    constraints.append(x[:, t + 1] == A @ x[:, t] + B @ u[:, t])

prob = cvxpy.Problem(cvxpy.Minimize(cost), constraints)
prob.solve()

The question is only after prob.solve() I can get u.value. Prior to that, within the loop, u[:, t].value returns none.
How to update xref[:, t] based on u[:, t] at each predictive time step?
